# How to run shell scripts at startup of Emacs/EXWM?

Tags: shell, exwm, script

I have configurations I would generally run on the startup of DWM. Now, I would like to do the same with EXWM/Emacs.

Is there any Elispian way to do it?

EDIT: arrived in conjunction with @lawlist
OBS: setbg is a script written and distributed by LARBS witch integrates with pywal and ewal themes on emacs.

(call-process "/usr/bin/bash" "~/.local/bin/setbg" "~/.emacs.d/wal/wall1.jpeg")

(start-process-shell-command
"setbg" nil "setbg ~/.emacs.d/wal/wall1.jpeg")

Both worked fine, and integrated nicely with EXWM.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: How about placing something like this in your `.emacs` / `init.el` file?:  `(call-process "/bin/bash" "/path/to/script.sh")`

Comment: Drew, I'm asking about Emacslisp interoperability capability, and use, with shell scripting! Is that off topic?

Comment: @lawlist Yes, it worked